# How to insulate static electricity?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, home-experiment

This is a follow up question to [Extending the reach of a crocodile clip for Kelvin Water Dropper experiment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/237151/105469).

We have resolved the issue, but now we have the following cable (in the image) that carries static electricity but should be isolated. When the cable is not touching the wood everything works (I.e when held in the air) but when it touches the wood it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, probably due to loss of electricity.

[image: cable]

We don't think that the problem is with the resistance or the air exposure but instead the insulation, and would like to know how can we create this kind of 'super' insulation.

We have thought about wrapping wires in the air and using insulating tape, but we'd prefer a cleaner/more elegant solution.

Comment: Clear plexiglass and air are your friend. They are cheap and reliably some  of the best insulators that you can find. Make a large cutout, mount a plexiglass sheet with a hole in it and run the cable trough the hole. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Long ago before the advent of modern superior specification HT (high tension = high voltage) leads which went from the distributor to the spark plugs in a motor car when it was damp it was sometimes very difficult to start a car.  One of the reasons for this was that there was a surface layer of moisture on the leads and at the voltages involved (25 kV)  there was a significant leakage current through the layer of moisture.  One way to improve matters was to clean the leads with an organic solvent and then spray the leads with an oil like WD40 which removed? the moisture.

Perhaps the first thing you should do is to clean the leads with an organic solvent and try not to handle them once they have been cleaned.
Another thing you could try is to dry the insulation around the leads with a fan heater.
WD40 might improve matters?

Answer (score 0):

At high voltage wood is a conductor, and you might not have a sufficient thickness of insulation on the wire. Monofilament fishing line is a great insulator, if you are looking to string it up somehow. Also, you might try slipping a piece of small diameter PVC pipe over your wire, PVC pipe is another good insulator. There are many other types of plastics (teflon for instance) that you might be able to source, but PVC is going to be a lot cheaper.